# I can't get the right window height for IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, window, height, cross-browser

I think I've tried everything to get the right window height in IE7 but all in vain.

Is there 1 surefire way to get the right window(viewport) height in IE7 and the other (better) browsers?

I've tried:

```
window.innerHeight(), 
document.innerHeight()
```

Jquery:

```
$(window).height(), 
$('body').height(), 
$('body').css('height')
```

The [website link](http://www.thechangery.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(window).height();
```

Will return the proper viewport height on IE7 - it could be how you're using it. If you try the following:

```
alert($(window).height());
```

You'll see its working (just tested IE7). If that simple bit of code doesn't work for you, make sure the jQuery library is loading properly, and make sure that you're checking the height inside a document.ready block.

Comment: WIll a timeout work? Maybe the document isn't ready? (loading some heavy images)

Comment: I also tried the code in IE8 with: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

Comment: Then it works, no problem. But not in a XP installed IE7, or through browsershots.org

Comment: I see my problem is with setting the right height, this method gives the right height, thanx